# MYSQL Foreign Key not Updating Table

Tags: mysql

Table 1:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| FONO         | int(11)     | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| Description  | varchar(25) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Amount       | varchar(60) | NO   |     |         |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table 2:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| FONO         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| FINVNO       | varchar(20) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Description  | varchar(25) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Amount       | varchar(60) | NO   |     |         |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I would like the Column FONO in table 1 automatically get the value from the FONO column in table 2. I have set it up so that on update it cascades.

Although when the records are being entered the FONO column in table 1 remains empty.

Why is this happening? What can I do to solve this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cascade happen on deleting and update the primary key that in which its foreign key is defined with cascade behavior and not insertion.

```
ON DELETE CASCADE

ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Just [check out more here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/)

Comment: So would I have to create a trigger inorder to get the column to gain the same value on insertion?

Comment: yeah, you can do it simply by running two insertion queries, i mean for table 2 then take primary key of table 2 insert it as a foreign key for table 1. i dont know what you want to do anyway